# How to call free() properly?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free, c99

Kindly read the whole post since it includes small details which are highly important.

As known by C we should take care of incidents where `malloc` fails, for that case I created a function called `destroyList()` whose job is to take a pointer to `Node` and destroy it one by one.
But my function isn't being called correctly...

I tried to call it with ptr, `merged_out` and `*merged_out` (The last one was a suggestion from a member of the community) but nothing seems to work.

**Why is that?** the function sometimes receives `NULL`, Empty Lists or some random values.

Can someone please help me fix this issue and let me understand of what is going on?

```
typedef struct node_t {
    int x;
    struct node_t *next;
} *Node;

void destroyList(Node ptr) {
    while (ptr) {
        Node toDelete = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free(toDelete);
    }
}
```

Main Function:

```
ErrorCode mergeSortedLists(Node list1, Node list2, Node *merged_out) {
    if (!list1 || !list2) {
        return EMPTY_LIST;
    }
    if (!isListSorted(list1) || !isListSorted(list2)) {
        return UNSORTED_LIST;
    }
    if (!merged_out) {
        return NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }
    Node ptr = NULL;
    int total_len = getListLength(list1) + getListLength(list2);
    for (int i = 0; i < total_len; i++) {
        int min = getMin(&list1, &list2);
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
        *merged_out = ptr;
        if (!ptr) {
            destroyList(*merged_out);
            *merged_out = NULL;
            return MEMORY_ERROR;
        }
        ptr->x = min;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        merged_out = &ptr->next;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**This is how the function should be called:**

```
Node merged_actual = NULL;
ErrorCode merge_status = mergeSortedLists(list1, list2, &merged_actual);
```

**Note**: `getMin()` gets the minimum value and advances the pointer of the list which has that min value to the next node.

Comment: err I get to understand why... You need to call destroy list with the head of the list, not `merged_out` as it points to the last element of the list...

Comment: to do so declare a static variable or something to store head upon the first call. Like `static Node head; static int flag=0; if (!flag){head=*merged_out;flag=1;}`

Comment: But how could I do that, I spent 3 days on this with no solution at all

Comment: I am not allowed to use static or global variables

Comment: @AdrianMole Sorry but not, I know the difference but wasn't able to point to the first node in my code

Comment: Then no. You get to have some way to store the head anyway as otherwise after your call from other functions you will have no way to access the list; you don't know the head! you can only access the last element.

Comment: Or you will have to not change merged_out, and iterate another pointer, say `i`, from *merged_out until i.next==NULL upon every access to the tail.

Comment: I tried to declare Node head=*merged_out but why this doesn't help?

Comment: may you kindly publish this as an answer? "Or you will have to not change merged_out,.."

Comment: You need the pointer-to-pointer in `mergedSortedLists`. And in `destroyList` pass the head address and skip that - check for `->next != NULL` before the loop.

Comment: There are so many posts here about linked lists, really.

Comment: @AdrianMole I know that I should pass the head but may you show me how please? I tried a lot with no sucess

Comment: It's very late here and way past sleep time. If somebody wants to answer, then fine, but we're strongly discouraged from answering questions that almost certainly have been answered before.

Comment: I swear I didn't find a solution 3 days with nothing, you can't imagine working on huge c code for 3 months and getting a mark of 0 only because I can't get one small function to work I got really disappointed. I barely sleep because of this and the deadline is only hours from now

Comment: This line is wrong: `merged_out = &ptr->next;`. Now `merged_out` no longer points to the caller's variable. It should be `*merged_out = ptr->next;`

Comment: @Barmar I changed it and my code doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start after those `if` checks.

```
    Node ptr=NULL,last;
    /* find out current tail of the list */
    if (*merged_out!=NULL){
        last=*merged_out;
        while (last->next!=NULL){
            last=last->next;
        }
    }
    int total_len = getListLength(list1) + getListLength(list2);
    for (int i = 0; i < total_len; i++)
    {
        int min = getMin(&list1, &list2);
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
        if (!ptr)
        {
            destroyList(*merged_out);
            *merged_out=NULL;
            return MEMORY_ERROR;
        }
        ptr->x = min;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        /* link ptr onto the list */
        if (*merged_out==NULL){
            /* if the list is empty, make ptr the head of the list */
            *merged_out=ptr;
            last=*merged_out;
        }
        else{
            last->next = ptr;
            last = ptr;
        }
    }
```

Please try not to copy and paste this block of code. It may or may not be correct, but try to understand what it did: iterate each time the function is called, in an effort to put `last` to point at the last element of the list. Therefore `merged_out` can always point to the head.

Comment: @smith_97 `if (*merged_out==NULL){
            *merged_out=ptr;
            ptr->next=NULL;
            last=*merged_out;
        }` so the first ptr becomes *merged_out if it is NULL

Comment: I made some edits still code doesn't run an it got really sophisticated

Comment: it seems to work, may you kindly try to simplify it or to make it more clear (Given the fact that *mergedout=NULL when I call the function and other things)?

Answer (score 0):

@user12986714 I lost my old account, and was told to not to care about the initial value of *merged_out could you update the solution (delete the first while loop and no need for 2 pointers)

Comment: 1) pinging someone in answers won't work and I received no notification. You may want to use comments next time 2) really? I don't believe it. Otherwise why are you posting offensive answers to your own question? [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706255/last-appeal-a-message-to-the-community/61706307#61706307)

Comment: also I can't see the necessity to edit the answer; you already know what to do, so just edit the code on your computer and hand in the edited version